# Unable to connect to your database using the configuration settings you submitted

Tags: database-error, install, ee5

I’m kind of lost on what’s going on here. We are trying to install EE and are getting the error “Unable to connect to your database using the configuration settings you submitted”. I’ve installed many instances of EE and never had an issue with this, but never on IIS. So my first guess is that IIS is the culprit in some way. Side note, I had to install PHP and MySQL Server myself, both of which I’ve never had to do before, so there could be something there as well.

In an attempt to remove variables from the equation, I wrote a quick php script to connect to the database with the credentials I supplied the EE Wizard and was able to successfully connect and write to the database.

I’m not sure what this tells me though, other than it has something to do with how EE is attempting to connect to the database.

I’m not expecting a definitive answer here, just a direction. Any help, guidance or hell even suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**ENVIRONMENT:**
- IIS - Windows Server 2016 Data Center
- PHP 7.3.5
- MySQL 8.0.16 - MySQL Community Server
- EE 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Could be a authenticate problem due a compatibility with MySQL 8

Here an article about this problem:

https://u.expressionengine.com/article/mysql-8-and-expressionengine-tips-for-the-trailblazers

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948350/phpmyadmin-on-mysql-8-0

Comment: Dang, I was really hoping that was it. Looks like my default_authentication_plugin variable was already set to mysql_native_password. Thanks though. You did give me the idea to install something like MySQL Server 5.x.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in my case. When installing PHP I left the pdo_mysql extension commented out. Uncomment, restart server and voila!